# How to change the legends from vertical view to horizontal view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I want to change the legends in vertical view into horizontal view.

```
voicecalldata
.width(400)
.height(190)
.x(d3.scale.ordinal())
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
.brushOn(true)
.dimension(voicecalldataDimension)
.group(Incoming1,"Incoming")
.group(Outgoing1,"Outgoing")
.legend(dc.legend().x(5).y(165).itemHeight(8).gap(3))
```

Here, voicecalldata is my `compositechart` name.

[image]

The above legend must be changed to this below format.
[image]

Someone please help me out.

Comment: Add `horizontal(true)`

Comment: Thanks man, that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
.legend(dc.legend().horizontal(true).x(5).y(165).itemHeight(8).gap(3))
```

Read more at:

http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.legend.html#horizontal__anchor

Comment: Do you know how to increase the gap between those horizontal legends?
I tried increasing the value of `gap()`, but it is not helping. `gap()` helps only if the legends are vertical.